# SFMC API - Change the timezone of the date in the response to a SOAP call

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

everyone,
by making the call to retrieve information from the Allsubscribers (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_subscriber.htm?search_text=CreateRequest), can you specify the return timezone for the date fields (CreatedDate, UnsubscribedDate, ect ect)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the desired timezone in any date filters for requests, but I believe all responses contain dates using server time which is is GMT-6.

Here is some documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/incoming_date_normalization.htm

Comment: And there is no daylight savings in the GMT-6.  So keep that in mind.

Comment: Hi Mike, so how would I have to do to get the dates in GMT format in response?
For example, how should I set the request below? Thanks
<RetrieveRequest>
<ObjectType>Subscriber</ObjectType>
<Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
<Properties>EmailAddress</Properties>
<Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
<Properties>Status</Properties>
<Filter xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="q1:SimpleFilterPart">
<q1:Property>SubscriberKey</q1:Property>
<q1:SimpleOperator>equals</q1:SimpleOperator>
<q1:Value>[subkeyl]</q1:Value>
</Filter></RetrieveRequest>

Comment: You cannot get the dates in GMT format in the Response - they are always server time which is GMT-6.  You will have to convert the date from the response.